# what to know the replacement of assert class and its method in spring 4.2.5 maven 3 also which dependency is use for it

Tags: java, maven, junit

There is error in `assertEquals()`, The method `assertEquals(int, int)` is undefined for the type `TATManagementServiceTestCase`.

I think this class is depricated so what is the replacement of this class and its method.My code:

```
package ae.edaman.tat.service;

import java.util.List;

//import org.springframework.test.AbstractDependencyInjectionSpringContextTests;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests;

import ae.edaman.common.exception.ApplicationException;
import ae.edaman.tat.model.ClientType;
import ae.edaman.tat.model.MemCountClassification;
import ae.edaman.tat.model.WorkflowStatusMapping;

public class TATManagementServiceTestCase extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests
//AbstractDependencyInjectionSpringContextTests 
{


    protected String[] getConfigLocations() {
        setAutowireMode(AUTOWIRE_BY_NAME);
          return new String[] {
             "applicationContext.xml" 
          };
       }

    private TATManagementService tatManagementService;


    public void testClaimsMapping() {
        Exception exception = null;
        List<WorkflowStatusMapping> workflowStatusList = null;
        try {
            WorkflowStatusMapping searchCriteria = new WorkflowStatusMapping();
            searchCriteria.setServiceCode("OCT");
            workflowStatusList = tatManagementService.findWorkflowStatusMapping(searchCriteria);
        } catch (ApplicationException ae) {
            exception = ae;
        }
        assert exception == null;
        assertEquals(8, workflowStatusList.size());//i have error in this line and also few more method like assertnull()

    }
```

I am not sending the complete code and if possible do give me complete dependency and method name .

Comment: You are using JUnit3 constructs in a JUnit4 environment. Use the `Assert` class from Unit instead of super methods.

Comment: can you explain how to use it plz .i am new for junit